# How to pass multiple plugins to Full Calendar Component in react

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar

I am calling the component FullCalendar in my code. For the Calendar I need two plugins to be loaded. The dayGridPlugin and the interactionPlugin. However when I pass them both in the attribute 'plugins', it only loads the first plugin I pass in. I could not find documentation on this specific problem which is why I'm asking here. I'm guessing I made a error in the way I pass them in.

```
            <FullCalendar 
                defaultView="dayGridMonth"
                plugins={[dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
                events={[
                { title: 'event 1', date: '2019-10-01' },
                { title: 'event 2', date: '2019-11-01' }
                ]}
                selectable='true'
            />
```

Answer (score 0):

The interaction plugin was working but I did not realize that I had to use the dateClick attribute and not the selectable attribute. The dateClick allows you to have a event handler for when for when a date is clicked. It is passed in as the parameter event.